# Как переписать эти DELETE и INSERT с mysqli на PDO php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Необходимо переписать старый код на новый с использованием транзакций из PDO. Есть вот такая конструкция с `DELETE`:

```
    if ($month && $day && $year && $div) {
        $result_ok = dbq("DELETE FROM $dbtable[visit] WHERE id_worker='" . $ar[id] . "' AND sdate='" . date('Y-n-j', $date) . "'");
    }
```

И с `INSERT`:

```
    if ($month && $day && $year && $div) {
        $result_ok = dbq("INSERT INTO $dbtable[visit] (id, id_worker, sdate, sdate_int, status, hours, id_author, cdate)
 VALUES (NULL, '" . $ar[id] . "', '" . date('Y-n-j', $date) . "', '" . $date . "', '" . $f_visit[$ar[id]] . "', '" . $f_hours[$ar[id]] . "', '$user_id', '$now[time]')");
        $f_id = mysql_insert_id();
    }
```

Функция `dbq`:

```
// Выполнение запроса к БД, v.1.1
function dbq ($cmd)
{
    GLOBAL $dbq_msg,$numrows;
    $result = @mysql_query($cmd);
    if ($result) {
           if ($dbq_msg=="a") echo "<br><b>SQL Ok</b>: $cmd";
        $numrows=@mysql_numrows($result);
        } else {
        if ($dbq_msg=="e" or $dbq_msg=="a") echo "<br><b>SQL Error</b>: ".mysql_error();
        }
    return $result;
}
```

Как это правильно переписать на PDO, чтоб безопасно было и в случае чего не удалялось лишнего?

Comment: желаю вам поскорее узнать о существовании `ORM`, и отказаться от `PDO` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом главное отличие - это передача переменных не напрямую в текст запроса, а в качестве массива. При этом в местах, где переменная должна появиться, ставится вопросительный знак.

```
$a = "foo";
$b = "bar";
$sql = $_database->prepare('INSERT INTO `tablename` (a, b) VALUES (?, ?)');
$result = $sql->execute([ $a, $b ]);
// >> INSERT INTO `tablename` (a, b) VALUES ('foo', 'bar')
```

**Подключение**

```
$_database = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'user', 'password');
```

**Удаление**

```
$sql = $_database->prepare('DELETE FROM '.$dbtable['visit'].' WHERE id_worker=? AND sdate=?');
$result = $sql->execute([
    $ar['id'],
    date('Y-n-j', $date)
]);
```

**Добавление**

```
$sql = $_database->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$dbtable['visit'].' (id, id_worker, sdate, sdate_int, status, hours, id_author, cdate) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$result = $sql->execute([
    $ar['id'],
    date('Y-n-j', $date),
    $date,
    $f_visit[$ar['id']],
    $f_hours[$ar['id']],
    $user_id,
    $now['time']
]);
```

Comment: А что возвращает `$result = $sql->execute`? Просто в этом моем коде дальше используется конструкция `if ($result_ok) {}` я могу как то сделать тоже самое? Узнать, удалилось ли и если удалилось, то перейти на другой url

Comment: Возвращает TRUE в случае успешного завершения или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки

Comment: понял, спасибо) просто выдает ошибку 500 при нажатию на кнопку submit и ничего не говорит) пытаюсь отладить) (проблема 100% не в подключении к бд))

Comment: А ваш код может из за чего то не работать? Удаление не происходит и получаю ошибку HTTP 500. Не могли бы вы подсказать в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Код не тестировал. Ошибку если и допустил, то только в синтаксисе. Я так понял код выполняется при отправке формы?

Comment: да, у вас ошибка в `DELETE FROM ?` не надо бандить название дб, это и есть причина ошибки) надо так `'DELETE FROM ' .$dbtable['visit'].` исправьте плиз, я так ответ как верный отметить не могу)

Comment: Все, отредактировал